# RegEx for capturing ticket ID's in a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to craft a RegEx that will isolate the ticket ID numbers in my URL and send them back to me in a bug report as seen below.

```
  const input = document.getElementById('nameInput')
        data = {
          "name": input.value || "Problem with ticket"+ window.location.href.match(/\d/),
          "story_type" : "Bug",
          "description": window.location.href
```

I have also tried pulling the whole URL

```
 "Problem with ticket"+ window.location.href.match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/)
```

However, both return "Problem with ticket Null", I admit I'm terrible at RegEx, so what would be the best way to write this? I've attached an example URL below.

```
https://xoxoxox.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/2116248
```

Comment: Start by using `window.location.pathname`, that would give you just `/agent/tickets/2116248` in this case. And if you still can't find a matching regex for that - then you can also just split it at the `/`, and pick the last part of the result.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `match(/\d+/)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following RegEx `\d+` for retrieving the required ID,

As demonstrated in the code snippet below,

```js
url = "https://xoxoxox.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/2116248";

let ticketID = url.match(/\d+/);
console.log(ticketID);
```

Read more about it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gFXBYi/1)

Answer (score 0):

If ticket ID is only digits.

```
"https://xoxoxox.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/2116248".replace(/.*\/(\d*)/,"$1")
```

Result : 2116248

Answer (score 0):

If there can be more digits in the url, you can make it specific to get it after tickets in a capture group.

Check first if there is a match, and then get the capture group 1 value:

```
\/tickets\/(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BRsYUJ/1)

```
let m = "https://xoxoxox.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/2116248".match(/\/tickets\/(\d+)/);
if(m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Output

```
2116248
```